# ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher using wcf with net.tcp binding

Tags: wcf, binding, net.tcp

My wcf service run correctly but when i add some more function it give error only on that functions:-

> The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IService/viewBlogType'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract
>   mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a
>   binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check
>   that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding
>   (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Comment: Did you do as the error message suggested?

Comment: *Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding* - did you already do that?

Comment: ya i do same  but i do not understand why only new functions are giving this error   plz help